Why isn't my Blazor Server app sending HTTP requests to my ASP.NET Core Web API?
I have a Blazor Server Web App and an ASP.NET Core Web API running on localhost. I am trying to make HTTP requests from the Web App to the API but I cannot see any requests being made in the browser's Network tab or any responses from the API. Despite configuring CORS and setting the correct HttpClient.BaseAddress, the requests don’t seem to reach the API.
I've tried:
1. Cors Configuration in WebAPI:
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddDefaultPolicy(policy =>
    {
        policy.WithOrigins("http://localhost:5235")
              .AllowAnyHeader()
              .AllowAnyMethod();
    });
});
app.UseCors();

2. HttpClient Configuration in WebApp:
builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient
{
    BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:5213/")
});

3. Test Endpoint using Razor page:
@page "/test-api-connectivity"
@inject HttpClient HttpClient

<h3>Test API Connectivity</h3>
<button @onclick="FetchData">Test Connection</button>
<p>@responseMessage</p>

@code {
    private string responseMessage = string.Empty;

    private async Task FetchData()
    {
        try
        {
            var response = await HttpClient.GetAsync("api/locations");
            responseMessage = response.IsSuccessStatusCode
                ? "Connection successful!"
                : $"Connection failed: {response.StatusCode}";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            responseMessage = $"Error: {ex.Message}";
        }
    }
}

Testing with Swagger and Postman:

The API works fine with Postman and Swagger.
The endpoint /api/locations returns 17,820 rows in Postman, so the API is functional.

Browser Debugging:

I don’t see any outgoing requests in the browser’s Network tab when clicking the "Test Connection" button.
No errors appear in the browser console.

When clicking the button on the test page (TestApiConnectivity or Locations), I expect the browser to send a GET request to http://localhost:5213/api/locations and return a response.
It has been frustrating to troubleshoot since: no HTTP requests are visible in the browser's Network and Console tab. The API does not log any received requests. And lastly, the Blazor page does not update with the response.
Question:
What could prevent my Blazor Server Web App from sending HTTP requests to the API, even though:

CORS is configured,
API works with Postman and Swagger,
The HttpClient.BaseAddress is set correctly?


if you add a breakpoint to FetchData, is the breakpoint being hit if you click the button?
